# SQLAlchemy session management in test-agnostic functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pytest

I'm working on a Python application that uses [the following SQLAlchemy pattern](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_transaction.html#joining-a-session-into-an-external-transaction-such-as-for-test-suites) for separating unit tests into isolated transactions, and using pytest fixtures:

```
@fixture(scope='function')
def session(engine):
    connection = engine.connect()
    transaction = connection.begin()
    Session = get_session(bind=connection)

    session = Session()
    session.begin_nested()

    @listens_for(session, 'after_transaction_end')
    def resetart_savepoint(sess, trans):
        if trans.nested and not trans._parent.nested:
            session.expire_all()
            session.begin_nested()

    yield session

    session.close()
    transaction.rollback()
    connection.close()
```

I'm defining the `get_session()` utility function such that I can also use it in my application code:

```
def get_session(bind=None):
    if bind is None:
        bind = create_engine(DATABASE_URL)
    return scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=bind))
```

This pattern works flawlessly in unit test code that uses the `session` fixture directly:

```
def test_foo(session):
    assert session.query(Foo).count() == 0
```

**However**, whenever I want to test application code that should access the session by itself, without it being passed explicitly from the unit test, I get a failure:

```
def create_foo_obj():
    Session = get_session()
    session = Session()
    session.add(Foo())
    session.commit()

def test_foo(session):
    create_foo_obj()
    assert session.query(Foo).count() == 1  # FAILS
```

Since I'm using a `scoped_session` I would expect that any application code that calls `get_session()` will get the same session that is bound from the test fixture, but that doesn't happen.

I know I can workaround this by passing the `session` directly to the function, but that seems just wrong.

Any better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Is monkeypatching `get_session` to use the `session` fixture returns an option?

Comment: @hoefling sure, do you have an example for that?

Comment: Your expectations would seem to be a bit off regarding "Since I'm using a scoped_session I would expect that any application code that calls get_session() will get the same session". The function seems to create a *new* scoped session (and session factory) per call. Also, passing a session to functions that need it is *right* in most cases.

Comment: @IljaEverilä my use case is testing Celery tasks. How would you manage sessions for those tasks? Currently my thought is to have a top level `Session` and create `session = Session()` within each task. Passing a session parameter to a celery task doesn't really make sense (it's probably not serializable). Is there a better way you can suggest?

Comment: Disclaimer: haven't used Celery ever, but sounds like you're on the right track in that a task is a natural lifetime for a `Session`, given that they're not too long lived. That way a tasks DB operations all succeed or fail as one etc., if you handle the transaction at the task level and the functions etc. used by the task just receive the session from the task. If possible, just make it so that the `Session` used by a task is injectable so that you can slip in a mock when necessary, or a test controlled one etc.